# javascript testing variables for setting cookies

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

i am getting nuts with something .

What i am trying to do is to set a cookie when loading a certain page so that when being on another page and the cookies has been set, the page is refreshed.

My condition tests do not react as how i expect it .

here is where i am at :

```
    $( window ).load(function() {       

        var page=$(".listing_voyage");

        //alert('page:'+page.length);
        //alert('cookie:'+getCookie('refresh'));

        if (getCookie('refresh') && page.length )       
        {                           
            window.location.reload(true); 
            SetCookie("refresh",false); 
            alert('i am reloading');
        }


    });



    var page_produit=$("#page_produit");
    if (page_produit.length)        
    {
        SetCookie("refresh",true);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you reload the page, the javascript is lost, and everything starts over

```
window.location.reload(true); // reloads page
SetCookie("refresh",false);   // and this is not executed, as the page reloaded
alert('i am reloading');
```

You'll have to set the cookie *before* reloading

```
 SetCookie("refresh",false); 
 window.location.reload(true);
```

But why exactly are you reloading the page to begin with, it seems like a strange thing to do ?